# any run-time configurable parser library for C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I have an inherited project that parses both binary and ascii data streams from various sources (fixed-repeat-length binary streams, fixed-repeat-length ascii streams, variable-repeat-length but fixed-number-of-fields csv-like ascii streams).  It is already run-time configurable as to on which input port to expect each format of input, defining either fixed length and what each group of bytes should be parsed as based on position, or for the variable length ones, which byte or set of bytes should be considered as the record separator and field separator, and what each field between the field separators should be parsed as.  The format of each stream is known before run-time and described in an ascii based config file.

However I now need this to be a little more generalizable to handle a new input device with basically an either-or type of grammar.  When the device is operating normally it outputs in the following line format, one line per second:

6.53m,48.31%

but when the device detects an out-of-range error condition, it outputs

999999

My current level of configurability (the inherited code) doesn't let me handle this, as it is firstly not fixed length, nor does it have a consistent number of field separators per "record", i.e. per line.

I need a parser configuration system that lets me say "if there's 2 fields in the record then parse a float followed by a string constant 'm', and a float followed by a string constant '%'; if there's only one field in the record, parse an int".

If anyone is aware of any packages out there that have addressed this type of need, I would appreciate pointers to them.  Obviously I've googled but I may not be using the correct terminology for this type of configurable parser so googling hasn't been very fruitful.

Comment: This seems like it should be easy in any reasonable parser generator, they should allow you to specify alternatives in a production.

Comment: Try parsing as one, and then the other?

Comment: Thank you for marking my question off topic.  Would you mind enlightening me as to how one is supposed to ask a question such as mine (or as you would have it, how to avoid asking the question) without already knowing a term like "parser generator"?  Care to list a "reasonable parser generator" as google for this is all over the subject universe.

Comment: The close reason isn't justified IMO, but as you apparently only missed the right key-word for a search, closing (with a different reason) is OK. What I don't understand are the downvotes. +1. A clear question, perhaps useful to others, and you apparently did some research.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use plain-old `sscanf` and friends to parse this. `sscanf` returns the number of fields successfully converted, which you can use to determine if the line parsed correctly. This doesn't even require a fancy parser generator!

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[256];

    while(fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {
        float f1, f2;
        int d1;
        if(sscanf(line, "%fm,%f%%", &f1, &f2) == 2) {
            printf("f1 = %f, f2 = %f\n", f1, f2);
        } else if(sscanf(line, "%d", &d1) == 1) {
            printf("d1 = %d\n", d1);
        } else {
            printf("Unrecognized input.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
6.53m,48.31%
f1 = 6.530000, f2 = 48.310001
999999
d1 = 999999
blah
Unrecognized input.
```

Comment: Thanks but you've answered this by encapsulating the expected format in code.  I'm looking for a package that lets me encapsulate the expected format in a config file and not recompile my code when my boss throws the next new device with different quirks at me.

Comment: You'll have to recompile the code to deal with the operational logic of the next device, anyway, so why bother with a complex config file setup? You are just going to run into trouble trying to anticipate any kind of future device.

Comment: (But, if it turns out to be a relatively simple "generalization", you can always just put the format strings in a file. That's one nice thing about C format strings.)

Comment: Um, re "you'll have to recompile the code to deal with the operational logic of the next device", um, no, the previous 20 or 30 devices ranging from GPS cards, to inertial measurement units, to altimeters, to magnetometers, that have been thrown my way have been all handled with run-time config file changes using what in-house parser configurability I have already.  Thanks anyway.